# Как отрендерить исходя из условия в React Js?

Tags: html, reactjs

если в реакте в зависимости от одного условия рендерится одна штука, иначе другая. например. такая проверка ужасно смотрится

```
{this.props.isCitizen ? <div className={s.Wrapper}>
      <div className={s.itemForm}>
          <Seleсt
              options={options.region}
              onChange={onSelectChange('region')}
          />
      </div>
      <div

          <Select

              value={values.city}

              options={options.city}
              onChange={onSelectChange('city')}
          />
      </div>
  </div>
: <div className={s.itemForm}>
      <Select

          value={values.country}

          options={options.country}
          onChange={onSelectChange('country')}
      />
</div>}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы добавил эти две штуки в отдельные элементы `React`, и сделал бы так:

```
const citizen1 = <div className={s.Wrapper}>
    <div className={s.itemForm}>
      <Seleсt
          options={options.region}
          onChange={onSelectChange('region')}
      />
    </div>
    <div
      <Select
        value={values.city}

        options={options.city}
        onChange={onSelectChange('city')}
      />
    </div>
</div>
const citizen2 = <div className={s.itemForm}>
    <Select
        value={values.country}

        options={options.country}
        onChange={onSelectChange('country')}
    />
</div>

{this.props.isCitizen ? citizen1: citizen2}
```

Comment: а чем плох способ через через css скрывать, добавляя класс hidden в реакте?